# Why does my sklearn.metrics confusion_matrix output look transposed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

It's my understanding that confusion matrices should show the TRUE classes in the columns and the PREDICTED classes in the rows. Therefore the sum of the columns should be equal to the value_counts() of the TRUE series.

I have provided an example here:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

pred = [0, 0, 0, 1]
true = [1, 1, 1, 1]

confusion_matrix(true, pred)
```

Why does this give me the following output? Surely it should be the transpose of that?

```
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion probably arises because `sklearn` follows a different convention for axes of confusion matrix than the wikipedia article. **So, to answer your question**: It gives you the output in that specific format because `sklearn` expects you to read it in a specific way.

Here are the two different ways of writing confusion matrix:

- [sklearn's way of reading/writing confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py): true labels in rows, and predicted labels in columns 
  [image]
- [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Example) opposite of `sklearn`
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn's confusion matrix` follows a specific order and structure.

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do as you wish using sklearn, only change the code below appropriately

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(7,4))

ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix(predict,y_test,labels=[1,0]),
                       display_labels=[1,0]).plot(values_format=".0f",ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel("True Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Predicted Label")
plt.show()
```