# How to invert the confusion matrix in Sklearn `plot_confusion_matrix` function?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

When using the `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` function, it plots a confusion matrix with actual values as rows and the predicted as columns. However, every other source I have seen sets up the matrix with actual values as columns and predicted as rows. Frankly, that approach seems better and Sklearn's way is truly *confusing*.

It would be great if the plot showed the matrix in that format. How would I achieve this?

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373488/why-does-my-sklearn-metrics-confusion-matrix-output-look-transposed) comes close to answer but it does not directly do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my sklearn.metrics confusion\_matrix output look transposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373488/why-does-my-sklearn-metrics-confusion-matrix-output-look-transposed)

Comment: It is close but after writing the question, I found the answer myself and posted it. The thread you referred to mostly repeats what I said  and the second answer is the close one but does not directly show how to plot an inverted matrix

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Sklearn provides another function to display the confusion matrix. Instead of taking the estimator and the validation sets, it directly accepts the matrix and plots it:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# Create the CM
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
# Flip it using Numpy and feed it to the display function
cmp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=['label_1', 'label_2'])

plt.xlabel('Actual')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')

cmp.plot();
```

It has also `display_labels` parameter to accept custom class labels before plotting. As we are feeding the function an inverted matrix, it is important you add custom axes labels. Here is the documentation for the function:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html